# Emit signal between two classes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

A am trying to make a program that takes a signal from one class and with activation of that signal I want to activate a slot in second class.

In my case the first class is the mainWindow class, this class is subClass of QMainWindow, and in this class is the slot that I want to activate.

This is mainWindow.cpp:

```
mainWindow::mainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

mainWindow::~mainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void mainWindow::slotForStatusBarMessage(QString string)
{
    statusBar()->showMessage(string);
}
```

The second class is the mainWidget class and it is a subclass of QWidget.

This is mainWidget.cpp:

```
mainWidget::mainWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    buttonAddNewRecord=new QPushButton("Add new record", this);

    layoutButton=new QHBoxLayout();
    layoutButton->addWidget(buttonAddNewRecord);

    layoutMain=new QVBoxLayout();
    layoutMain->addLayout(layoutButton);

    functionDatabaseOpen();

    setLayout(layoutMain);
}
```

The signal is emited from functionDatabaseOpen() function:

```
if (sqlDatabase.open())
{
    emit signalForShowMessageInStatusBar("true");
}
else
{
    emit signalForShowMessageInStatusBar("false");
}
```

I have made all the settings to the database but i didnt copy here because of space.

I have tried to make connection inside main.cpp but it seems it dosent work.

```
QObject::connect(mw, SIGNAL(signalForShowMessageInStatusBar(QString)), w, SLOT(slotForStatusBarMessage(QString)));
```

I cant make this signal/slot connection between classes to work. Can you give me any help.

If you have any question about the code please ask. Sorry for the bad english,I am not a native english speaker.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What errors does the compiler give ? Where do you instantiate both classes ?

Comment: If the code compiles, pay attention to stdout or debug output -- Qt will print stuff if it needs to invoke a signal and can't find the connected slot.

Comment: @alexisdm this is output of:Starting /home/kudic/untitled136-build-desktop/untitled136...
/home/kudic/untitled136-build-desktop/untitled136 exited with code 0

Comment: I instatiate both classes in main.cpp, I also in main.cpp call for QObject::connect

Comment: Did you put the `Q_OBJECT` macro in mainWidget (for mainWindow QtCreator probably did it for you), and are the slots and signals declared in the `slots:` and `signals:` sections ?

Comment: I have Q_OBJECT macro in mainWidegt and in mainWindow, slots and signal all are declared in the right place.

Comment: QObject::connect returns boolean, try to check if connection was successful by checking its return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are emitting the signal from the constructor of `mainWidget`, and since the connection is only done after you return from that constructor, the signal doesn't go anywhere.

The easiest fix, not knowing what the rest of the code looks like, would be to move the call to `functionDatabaseOpen()` in `main()` after the signal/slot connection is made.

Comment: I think its safe to say that emitting a signal from within a constructor never makes sense, since you would never be able to make a connection to it in time. Good catch. +1

Comment: @alexisdm thank you I didnt know that emit cant be used in constructor, that is whay emiting didnt work